# Triggering kubernetes job for a kafka message

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka

I have a kubernetes service that only does something when it consumes a message from a Kafka queue. The queue does not have messages very often, and running the service as a job triggered whenever a message is found would save resources.

I see that Kubernetes has this functionality for AMQP-type message services: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/job/coarse-parallel-processing-work-queue/

Is there a way to adapt this for Kafka, given that Kafka does not support AMQP? I'd switch to a different messaging system, but I have other services that also read from this queue that require Kafka.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That Kafka consumer `Service` is all you really need. If you want to save resources, this could be paired with [KEDA](https://keda.sh/) autoscaler such that it scales up and down, depending on load or consumer group lag.

Or you can use serverless platforms such as [KNative](https://knative.dev/docs/eventing/sources/kafka-source/) to trigger based on Kafka (or other messaging systems) events.

> Kafka does not support AMQP

Kafka Connect *should* be able to bridge AMQP to Kafka. E.g. Apache Camel has connectors for both.

Comment: Thanks! The KEDA approach looks like a good compromise. At first glance, KNative and Kafka Connect both seem to require an extra kubernetes service, which would defeat the purpose of replacing our own service with a job. I'll look into them in more depth if the KEDA approach doesn't pan out.